# Invalid prop 'paddingLeft' when doing an Animation

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to use a React Native Animation to remove a padding(by making it `0`) and then to put it back.

The following code is managing the animations:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.animatedValueLateralPadding = new Animated.Value(Constants.LIST_ITEM_MARGIN * this.props.dimensions.windowWidth);
  }



componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.index == this.props.element.ordinalNumber) {
      Animated.stagger(Constants.RESIZED_TIME, [
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(this.animatedValueLateralPadding, {
              toValue: 0,
              duration: Constants.RESIZE_TRANSITION_TIME
            }),
          ]),
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(this.animatedValueLateralPadding, {
              toValue: Constants.LIST_ITEM_MARGIN * nextProps.dimensions.windowWidth,
              duration: Constants.RESIZE_TRANSITION_TIME
            }),
          ])
      ]).start();
    }
  }
```

In my `render` method I specify the style like this:

```
  const animatedStyle = {paddingLeft: this.animatedValueLateralPadding, paddingRight: this.animatedValueLateralPadding};
```

And then `animatedStyle` is used in this component which is returned:

```
    <ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={[listStyles.container, animatedStyle]}
      > 
     //some other code
```

The rest of the style is this:

```
const listStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: Constants.COLOR_BLACK,
    minHeight: '100%'
  }
});
```

The problem is that the padding does not disappear and I am getting this warning:

```
Failed prop type:Invalid prop 'paddingLeft' supplied to 'ScrollView'. Bad object:
{
  "backgroundColor": "#000000",
  "minHeight": "100%",
  "paddingLeft": 18,
  "paddingRight": 18
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't like how I specified `paddingLeft`.

I tried to pass a `String` instead of `Int` all to the `Animated.Value` object:

```
this.animatedValueLateralPadding = new Animated.Value(String.valueOf(Constants.LIST_ITEM_MARGIN * this.props.dimensions.windowWidth));
```

and

```
 toValue: String.valueOf(0),
```

and

```
 toValue: String.valueOf(Constants.LIST_ITEM_MARGIN * nextProps.dimensions.windowWidth)
```

However, I am getting:

```
Error while updating property: 'paddingLeft' in shadow node of type: RCTView

null

Unknown value: function String() {
   [native code]
}0
```

So why does it have a problem with the way in which I specify the padding?  Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: This is React Native style, not CSS. The names are camel cased.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Animated` components like `Animated.View`, `Animated.Text` to have this animation.
Consider reading this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html

Just change your `ScrollView` to `Animated.ScrollView`